# How to skip using MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in a single specific case

Tags: django

I have a question about overriding MEDIA_ROOT in some cases. In my case I am importing XML files which they are very large e.g. more than 100 MB. I am also using AWS for my uploaded media files. When I upload an XML file for parsing it's contents it uploads to AWS and I needed to download it again. So, is there a way override and not to upload it to AWS and use local file storage. I succeeded to overriding the storage parameter as below in my model:

```
fs = FileSystemStorage(location=settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/XML_Uploads/')

class ImporterFile(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    file = models.FileField(storage=fs)
    ....
```

It uses the overriden path when I upload the file. But the problem is when I check it in the admin interface it shows the wrong location for the path. It still shows a path something like "/media/filename.xml" . But in that case it must be /static/filename.xml

I could not find a way how to overcome this issue.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT & MEDIA_URL are different 
MEDIA_ROOT means you are storing the media files there.. but MEDIA_URL is the url through you can access the file

Answer (score 1):

MEDIA_ROOT & MEDIA_URL are different, `MEDIA_ROOT` means you are storing the media files there.. but MEDIA_URL is the url through you can access the file

extend `FileSystemStorage` class and set [base_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage.base_url) value

```
class MyStorage(FileSystemStorage):
      base_url = '/custom/url/'

fs = MyStorage(location=settings.STATIC_ROOT + '/XML_Uploads/')

class ImporterFile(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=fs)
```